# Can not copy files after installing windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, ntfs, partition-recovery

I am experiencing a weird problem. I was running Xubuntu on my laptop until yesterday that I had to delete Xubuntu and install Windows.
I had a NTFS partition on my Xubuntu that I kept some files on it. Today after installing windows I wanted to move all the files from that partition to an external HDD. I selected all files and folders and clicked on Copy, then I went to the HDD and clicked on paste but nothing happened. I can not do that. I do not know why. I copy the files, and wherever I click paste, nothing happens.
If I try to copy the files and folders one by one, I can copy some of them, but some of them do not move.
The other problem I have is that I can not open some files, in particular pdf files. When I click on pdf files I get this error:

```
There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found.
```

Also, I cannot play some mp4 files. I can not open some jpg and txt files.
I get this error

```
The directory name is invalid.
```

So in summary, after removing Xubuntu and installing windows 7 I have the following problems with one of the NTFS partitions on my internal drive:

- Can not copy or cut all folders and files from that partition to any other partition - I also do not get any errors.
- Can copy some folders and files
- Can not access some pdf, jpeg, txt and mp4 files and get the above errors.

I should also mention I did not change anything for this partition during the installation or formatting the other partitions.

Comment: I think there is differences in Xubuntu NTFS and Windows NTFS.  Have a look at this question that was posted on askUbuntu.  Could maybe give you some direction to reading the files from that partition. [Click Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20853/mount-ubuntus-partition-on-windows-7)

Comment: I did not format this partition in linux. This partition was formatted in Windows long time ago, and was working perfect in linux.